# Validate zip code in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zip

What would be the best way to validate a zip code in jQuery, I'm not talking about if its a 5 character number, I'm talking about a VALID zip code, like it checks with some service to make sure its valid.  By a valid zip code I mean a zip code in the USA that belongs to a City and State.

Comment: Define VALID zip code in your case

Comment: Do you get all the zip codes with some api or may be if you store them  in a json structure then you can validate them.

Comment: use `json` or `jsonp` as per this : `it checks with some service to make sure its valid.`

Comment: Use a service like those provided by [usps](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-address-information.htm?)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm talking about a VALID zip code, like it checks with some service to make sure its valid.

```
var zipCode = getTheZipCodeFromSomeWhere();
jQuery.getJSON("http://example.com/some-service", { zipCode:zipCode }, function(data) {
    updateZipCodeValidity(data.isZipValid);
});
```

You'll need to define `getTheZipCodeFromSomeWhere()`, `updateZipCodeValidity()` and `http://example.com/some-service` as appropriate to your situation.

Comment: You probably need to define `http://example.com/some-service` as well.

Comment: @Jack Good point - I'll add that to the answer